Looking for a functional satisfying $f(xf(y)) = \frac{f(x)}{y}$
I am looking for a functional $f:\mathbb{R}^*_+ \to \mathbb{R}^*_+$ satisfying:
$$
f(xf(y)) = \frac{f(x)}{y}.
$$
By replacing $x=y=1$ we get $f(f(1)) = f(1)$ but it does not give much information so $f \circ f=f$ kind of like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ but it does not work.

Did you mean a "function"?

The functions which satisfy this property are exactly the multiplicative functions satisfying $f(f(x))=1/x$ for all $x$. Firstly, it is clear that any multiplicative function with $f(f(x))=1/x$ works. For the other direction, we show:

$f$ is bijective. Plugging in $x=1$ gives $f(f(y))=f(1)/y$, so $f$ is bijective with inverse function $f^{-1}(t) = f(1)/f(f(y))$.

$f(1)=1$. Indeed, plugging in $x=y=1$ gives $f(1)=f(f(1))$, and applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides gives the result.

$f$ is multiplicative. Indeed, plugging in $(f(x),y)$ and then $(1,x)$ and $(1,xy)$ gives
$$f(f(x)f(y))=\frac{f(f(x))}y=\frac1{xy}=f(f(xy)).$$
Now, apply $f^{-1}$.


Now, functions with these properties exist, but they are rather weird. Define $g(x)=\log f(e^x)$, a function from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. This function must be additive, and must satisfy $g(g(x)) = -x$ for all $x$. Let $B$ be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then all additive functions are determined from functions $B\to\mathbb R$. Let $\sigma$ be an involution on $B$, and let $C$ be a subset of $B$ containing exactly one of $\{b,\sigma(b)\}$ for each $b\in B$. Choose an additive $g$ so that $g(b)=\sigma(b)$ for $b\in C$ and $g(b)=-\sigma(b)$ for $b\not\in C$. This function satisfies $g(g(x))=-x$ on $B$, and so it satisfies $g(g(x))=-x$ on all of $\mathbb R$. Then $f(x)=e^{g(\log x)}$ satisfies the functional equation in the problem.

Setting $x=1=y$, we get $f(f(1))=1$. Then, plugging back into the functional equation the values $x=1$ and $y=f(1)$, we get $f(f(f(1)))=1$, so $f(1)=1$ $(1)$.
Setting, $x=1$ and $y=x$ we get the equation $f(f(x))=\frac{f(1)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$ $(2)$, due to $(1)$.
Setting, $x$ to be arbitrary and $y=f(\frac{1}{x})$ we get $$f\left(xf\left(f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\right)=\frac{f(x)}{f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)},$$
and so by $(2)$ we get $f(\frac{1}{x})f(x^2)=f(x)$ $(3)$.
Setting, $f(x)$ for $x$ and $y=x$, we get $f(f^2(x))=\frac{f(f(x))}{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$ $(4)$, due to $(2)$. Thus, by combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we deduce that
$$f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)f(f^2(x))=f(f(x)),$$
so
$$\frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{x},$$
or equivalently,
\begin{equation} 
f\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=x, (5).
\end{equation}
Now, setting $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ back into the original equation we get
$$f\left(xf\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)\right)=f^2(x),$$
and so by $(5)$, it's $f(x^2)=f^2(x)$. Thus, by $(3)$ we get $f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{f(x)}$, and this is how far I can get.
